# What is proper format for calling Etherpad in iframe

Tags: etherpad

I'm trying this way to call etherpad on a web page.

```
<iframe src='http://pad.domain/p/PAD_NAME?sessionID=sessionID&authorName=authorName&userName=userName&showChat=false&showLineNumbers=false' width=600 height=400></iframe>
```

Is this the correct way to include an etherpad on a web page?

When I use this way and then call /setHTML API, changes done by API getting saved in DB but never reflect in pad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I've called etherpad like below and it's working perfectly fine.

```
<iframe src='http://pad.domain/p/PAD_NAME&authorName=authorName&showChat=false&showLineNumbers=false' width=600 height=400></iframe>
```

Also, /setHTML API is working fine now, when using with unique padID.May main mistake was in calling of etherpad.